# “hdparm -S” does not work on external HDD's. How to avoid it from spinning down?

Tags: hard-disk, hdparm

Apparently, `hdparm` only works with internal HDD's.
How do I avoid an external HDD from spinning down after half a minute?

One way is to read one sector using `badblocks` or `dd` each 29 seconds in an infinite loop.

Is there another way to keep the HDD spinning?

Edit: SMART is also not supported by that HDD. `hdparm -y` also does not work, but works for a different external HDD.

Comment: Make and model of HD?

Comment: @roaima Intenso Box 4TB. Very common in Europe.

Comment: That's the make of the casing. What's the make and model of disk?

Comment: @roaima Model of the disk? Not sure. (`lsblk -S` does only show “External USB 3.0 HDD” or something similar.)

Answer (score 2):

From the DESCRIPTION paragraph of `man hdparm`:

> `hdparm` provides a command line interface to various kernel interfaces supported by the Linux SATA/PATA/SAS "libata" subsystem and the older IDE driver subsystem. Many newer (2008 and later) USB drive enclosures now also support "SAT" (SCSI-ATA Command Translation) and therefore may also work with `hdparm`. E.g. recent WD "Passport" models and recent NexStar-3 enclosures. Some options may work correctly only with the latest kernels.

So yes, `hdparm` will work with *some* external HDDs: basically all eSATA HDDs and those USB HDDs which are using SCSI-ATA Command Translation.

For specifically Western Digital HDDs, [there is also the `idle3-tools` package](http://idle3-tools.sourceforge.net/). If you can read the SMART information from your WD external drive, then `idle3-tools` should also work.

And it's likely you could take the drive out of the enclosure, plug it into an internal SATA cable, use `hdparm` to change its settings persistently, and then place it back into the external enclosure. Of course that voids the warranty, if you care about that...

Comment: The only problem is that in most consummer grade controllers SMART lies a lot/is not properly implemented.

Comment: The idea is, if the USB-to-SATA adapter chip in the external enclosure can pass through the SMART commands, then the commands of the `idle3-tools` should also pass through the adapter chip to the actual disk.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1215772/644005

Basically, it says to use `sdparm` rather than `hdparm`. I was able to get it to work on all of my external Western Digital USB 3.0 HDDs.

This is the command I ran to disable the drive going into sleep mode:

```
sudo sdparm -l --save --set STANDBY=0 /dev/sd?
```

It also mentions the `SCT` setting, which refers to the timeout value. I didn't change the `SCT` value. If you want to increase the timeout value you can do it like this:

```
sudo sdparm -l --save --set SCT=6000 /dev/sd?
```

The `SCT` value is in milliseconds, so **6000** means **6 seconds**.

Answer (score 0):

iheartcsharp's answer *even works on Windows*. Compiling sdparm with MinGW didn't work, it didn't recognize SCT or STANDBY, but the latest sdparm_64 binary I could find, [1.10 20160222](https://sg.danny.cz/sg/p/sdparm_64.exe), from [here](https://sg.danny.cz/sg/sdparm.html#__RefHeading___Toc168_3041630551), **did work.**

My external 12 TB Elements drive was seemingly spun down whenever I went to copy files to it, whereas my other external Seagate drive has practically never spun down. sdparm's output backs that up.

```bash
Administrator@~ MINGW64 /j/compile/sdparm/src
# ./sdparm_64.exe --wscan
...
PD13    [K]     WD        Elements 25A3     1029  serial#

Administrator@~ MINGW64 /j/compile/sdparm/src
# ./sdparm_64.exe PD13
    PD13: WD        Elements 25A3     1029
Power condition mode page:
  PM_BG         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]

Administrator@~ MINGW64 /j/compile/sdparm/src
# ./sdparm_64.exe --get SCT PD13
    PD13: WD        Elements 25A3     1029
SCT           18000  [cha: y, def:18000, sav:18000]

Administrator@~ MINGW64 /j/compile/sdparm/src
# ./sdparm_64.exe --save --set STANDBY=0 PD13
    PD13: WD        Elements 25A3     1029

Administrator@~ MINGW64 /j/compile/sdparm/src
# ./sdparm_64.exe --get STANDBY PD13
    PD13: WD        Elements 25A3     1029
STANDBY       0  [cha: y, def:  1, sav:  0]

Administrator@~ MINGW64 /j/compile/sdparm/src
# ./sdparm_64.exe --get SCT PD13
    PD13: WD        Elements 25A3     1029
SCT           18000  [cha: y, def:18000, sav:18000]

Administrator@~ MINGW64 /j/compile/sdparm/src
# ./sdparm_64.exe --save --set SCT=999999999 PD13
    PD13: WD        Elements 25A3     1029
mode select (10):
Fixed format, current; Sense key: Recovered Error
Additional sense: Rounded parameter

Administrator@~ MINGW64 /j/compile/sdparm/src
# ./sdparm_64.exe --get SCT PD13
    PD13: WD        Elements 25A3     1029
SCT           288000  [cha: y, def:18000, sav:288000]

Administrator@~ MINGW64 /j/compile/sdparm/src
# ./sdparm_64.exe --get STANDBY PD12
    PD12: Seagate   Expansion Desk    9401
STANDBY not found in Power condition mode page

Administrator@~ MINGW64 /j/compile/sdparm/src
# ./sdparm_64.exe --get SCT PD12
    PD12: Seagate   Expansion Desk    9401
SCT not found in Power condition mode page
```

288 seconds seems to be the maximum spindown time, but it shouldn't matter with standby set to 0.

Probably bad form to add this as a "top level" answer, but this is one of the first search results I got while trying to figure out how to keep this drive from going to sleep, hoping it helps someone.